# Geoserver and SLD - continuous zooming of points?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, sld

I'm working with sld files and geoserver and I faced a problem about zooming in points at certain scale.

Is it possible to zoom in a point layer so that points get bigger continuously like polygons on a typical polygon layer?

Later I will have other layer on which this point layer will be put. The other layer includes grid. Points should stay same size as the grid cells all the way when zooming in and out. The default setting seems to be that points get smaller when zoomed in. I have found those Min and MaxScale settings but I would not like to set some certain size to the points.

Answer (score 2):

By default point sizes are measured in pixels and so will change size as you zoom in and out of your map. The Symbology Encoding standard allows you to specify the size of your points (and other features) in map units which will remain the same real world size as you zoom in and out, that is they seem to get bigger as you zoom in like polygons do.

You need to inform GeoServer what units you would like to use, for example 6m points could be styled as:

```
     <PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
        <Graphic>
          <Mark>
            <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
            <Fill>
               <CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
           </Mark>
          <Size>6</Size>
         </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
```